# Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found. error

Tags: django, python-3.x, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to deploy Django project to IBM Blumix with Cloud Foundry command line Interface[CF]. But I stacked.

I'm using on local PC below.

MacOS X
  Python3.5
  Django1.9
  CF 1.6.1

```
-----> Downloaded app package (8.0K)
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/python-buildpack'...
Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/compile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
-------> Buildpack version 1.5.3
-----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.10)
Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/concourse-binaries/python/python-2.7.10-linux-x64.tgz]
-----> Installing dependencies with pip
Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed
```

I wonder why runtime becomes python-2.7.10 even I write python-3.5.0 in runtime.txt.
Please give me any hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I might figured out.
I had put manifest.yml and requirements.txt and runtime.txt and run.sh on parents directory. It was not right place.

```
BMSample
 + BMSample
    + manifest.yml
    + requirements.txt
    + run.sh
    + runtime.txt
    + settings.py
 + manage.py
 ↓ incollect ↓
(+ manifest.yml)
(+ requirements.txt)
(+ run.sh)
(+ runtime.txt)
```